# Truffle Test: Again (Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert) with different SC

Tags: truffle-test

I posted a similar problem at:
[similar with different SC but sorry no solution yet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115477/how-to-solve-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert-maybe-because-my)

Following are my smart contracts (SCs)

==
SC F1

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
contract F1{
   address public owner;
   uint public bal= 1 ether;
   constructor() public {
       owner = msg.sender;
   }
   function() external payable {
     bal = bal + msg.value;
   }
}
```

==and my testing contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/F1
// Truffle will send the TestContract one Ether after deploying the contract.
contract TestF1{
uint public initialBalance = 1 ether;
function testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract() public {
   F1 f1 = F1(DeployedAddresses.F1());
   // perform an action which sends value to myContract, then assert.
   address(f1).transfer(10);
   Assert.equal(f1.bal(), 0, "Ether transferred");
}
function () external payable {
   // This will NOT be executed when Ether is sent. \o/
}
}
```

and my 2_deploy.contracts.js

```
const F1 = artifacts.require("F1");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(F1);
};
```

I am getting following error during truffle test:
$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.

## Compiling your contracts...

> Compiling ./contracts/F1.sol
> Compiling ./test/TestF1.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test--13270-blknLiBqwAGU
> Compiled successfully using:

- solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang
   
  TestF1

1. testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract

> No events were emitted

```
0 passing (6s)
 1 failing
 1) TestF1
 testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract:
 Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
 at Context.TestCase (/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:92:1)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
         
 @lc2530hz:~/Truffle_programs/TransferEther2$ truffle version
 Truffle v5.1.67 (core: 5.1.67)
 Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
 Node v10.23.3
 Web3.js v1.2.9
 @lc2530hz:~/Truffle_programs/TransferEther2$
```

Comment: What's the value returned by `f1.bal()`?

Comment: @Ismael
solved removed the bal and instead used the built-in balance variable.